# How do you visualize Stone-Čech compactification (construction using the unit interval)?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, geometric-construction, compactification

I think I understand the mechanism of constructing Stone-Čech well from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification).

However, I fail when trying to connect this with any concrete examples. For example, for the simplest examples, like $\mathbb{R}$, how do we construct $\beta \mathbb{R}$? I really couldn´t find any explicit construction anywhere, so any example would be appreciated.

I have read that "we do not construct Stone-Čech compactification. we just define it and prove it exists", but I still want to believe, haha.

Comment: "I want to visualize it.  I want an explicit construction."  Knowing that the existence requires the Axiom of Choice suggests that these are unlikely.

Comment: The Wikipedia article makes clear that there is rarely an easy description of the S-C compactification.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, the description also sounds easy to me. But why cannot I find any examples then?

Comment: You can show that the SC-compactification is strictly larger than the one-point compactification $S^1$.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the unit interval construction, but I found the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ much more tangible using the construction as the space of $z$-ultrafilters on $X$, with the canonical closed set base consisting of sets of the form $\{p \in \beta X : A \in p\}$ where $A \subset X$ is closed. A really good book for this kind of construction is Gillman and Jerison's "Rings of Continuous Functions". But typically these spaces are too large to warrant any kind of explicit visualization or example.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Okay, and how do you show that? Would you have any resources please? I can imagine the one point and two point comp. of $\mathbb{R}$, but still cannot see the closure od $\mathbb{R}$ in many copies of unit interval, as is the Stone-Čech.

Comment: @jl00 So, as far as I understand, the ultrafilters construction is used even for non discrete spaces? I thought it is only for discrete ones.

Comment: Tereza Tizkova. You check that the universal property of the SC-compactification fails for $S^1$. I.e. you find a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to K$ where $K$ is some compact space such that $f$ does not extend uniquely to a function $f: S^1 \to K$, where the canonical embedding $\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow S^1$ is implicit.

Comment: In the ultrafilter construction for non-discrete spaces, you pass to $z$-ultrafilters instead, which means maximal filters consisting of zero-sets of $X$. In the discrete case, these notions coincide (since every subset of $X$ is a zero-set).

Comment: @GEdgar: I think axiom of choice is needed to prove compactness, not existence (of $\beta X$ constructed using $[0,1]$).

Comment: @tomasz ... if you look at it that way, (construct $\beta \mathbb N$ using $[0,1]$: then ZF cannot prove $\beta\mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Sure. It may not be very interesting. Although with at least DC, I think you can show that it still has the universal property that every map from $X$ to a compact Hausdroff space uniquely factors through this $\beta X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only for very rare spaces ($\omega_1$ in the order topology is one) do we have a concrete space that is provably the Cech-Stone compactification of $X$. We cannot answer many questions on $\beta \Bbb N$ (the naturals as a countable discrete space) in standard set theory. For that space, as well as $\beta \Bbb R$ there are many papers with some results (we know some things in some models of set theory), van Douwen, van Mill, KP Hart, Comfort, Kunen and many others have written on the C-S compactifications of these spaces and still much is unknown. We "know" (believe) it exists because the Axioms of Choice tells us this, but we only have a "fuzzy image" of it. It's a useful but elusive object.

Answer (score 2):

For some basic information see

- Dow, Alan, and Klaas Pieter Hart, “[The Čech-Stone Compactification](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/d17-betaX.pdf)”, chapter d–17 (pp. 210–212) in *Encyclopedia of General Topology*, Elsevier, 2004
- Dow, Alan, and Klaas Pieter Hart, “[The Čech-Stone Compactifications of $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/d18-betaN-and-betaR.pdf)”, chapter d–18 (pp. 213–217) in *Encyclopedia of General Topology*, Elsevier, 2004